# What is the sum of the squares of the 10th roots of unity?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Obviously the sum of the roots of unity is 0, but is there a way to calculate this other than calculating them all individually and squaring them?

Comment: The square of a tenth rooot is a fifth root ...

Answer (score 5):

We have $q^n-1 =(q-1)(1+q+\ldots+q^{n-1})$.

Thus if $\xi$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, $\xi^n=1$ and so $1+\xi+\ldots+\xi^{n-1}=0$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

square of 10th root of unity is a fifth root of unity. can you prove the sum is 0?

You have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^9 e^{-ik\pi/10} = 0,
$$
and you are asked to compute
$$
\sum_{k=0}^9 \left(e^{-ik\pi/10}\right)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^9 e^{-ik\pi/5},
$$
which is zero as well because it is just traversing the 5-roots twice.

Comment: I don't get you?

Comment: @AnoUser1 see update

Comment: got you. but how are we meant to know what each individual root is, without having an angle?

Comment: @AnoUser1 i don't understand what you are asking? you know you have 10-roots, which when squared give you $10/2=5$-roots, twice

Comment: I'm used to doing roots of unity from having r and theta but you're not given one here. That's whats got me

Comment: @AnoUser1 for this to be $n$-th root of unity, $r=1$ and $\theta = k\pi/n$ with $0 \le k < n$.

Answer (score 1):

The square of a tenth root is a fifth root. From any fifth root you get two tenth roots. Different fifth roots give rise to two different tenth roots.

Thus you're summing twice the fifth roots.

Comment: I don't get you at the moment. How can you even find out what one of the roots is without knowing what R is?

Comment: @AnoUser1 You say you know that the sum of the tenth roots is $0$. That's true, but it also works for the $n$-th roots, for any integer $n>1$ (hint: Viète's formulas).

Comment: Yeah I know the sum of the nth roots is 0 but I don't get how the square of the 10th root is the 5th root

Comment: @AnoUser1 $1=x^{10}=(x^2)^5$.

Comment: I'm still not following sorry. How do we know x^10 is 1?

Comment: @AnoUser1 If $x$ is a tenth root of unity, then *by definition* $x^{10}=1$.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood the whole question now. Is it saying that there are ten roots of unity, to square them all and find the sum of them?

Comment: @AnoUser1 Yes, that's what you're asked to do. The brute force method obviously works, but there is the shorthand I showed you.

Comment: Ok so the 8th root squared is also the same as the 4th root etc?

Comment: Hoes does this work if we were looking at sum of squares of 7th root of unity instead?

Comment: @patentfox If $G$ is the group of 7th roots of unity, then the map $\zeta\to\zeta^2$ from $G$ to $G$ is an automorphism. You're simply summing the 7th roots.